# summation of count of the data from two tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want the total count of the columns from two tables.

I am trying this but it gives the total from one table but I want the summation from bot the tables

```
select DISTINCT(video_id), 
    (select count(*) as cnt from votes 
        where video_id = voteable_id 
        AND votes.type = "up") as order_col
from video_views  
ORDER BY `order_col`  DESC**
```

Video_views Table

```
video_id

    137
    136
    134
    137
    136
    137
```

Votes Table

```
   Voteable_id                     type

    137                             up
    137                             up
    134                             down
    135                             up
    134                             up
    134                             up
```

Its result should be

```
video_id   count
137        5
134        3
136        2
135        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select vedio_id,sum(cnt)
from
(
select video_id, count(*) as cnt from Video_views
group by video_id
union all
select Voteable_id, count(*) from Votes where votes.type = "up"
group by Voteable_id
)A group by vedio_id
```

Comment: @forpas, but looking at the sample data, it didn't seem to me that required. What do u think?

Comment: First, I did not downvote. Now by looking at 134, the count expected is 3 although there are 4 in the UNION.

Comment: Why it is down voted? Expain before your great effort

Comment: Thanks for quick and useful reply.

Comment: why accepted answer with 3 downvotes? whats problem?

Comment: Since there is no explanation for the downvotes (+1)

Comment: I can't see any reason for down vote. This is strange.